# Block java from using certain libraries

Tags: java

Environment: Introduction to Java class programming labs.

Is it possible to force Java to throw an exception if any imports for banned classes are used? For example, I have a lab where I specifically want them to calculate some geometry and I do not want them to just use built-in libraries.

Current solution: Grep all the java files for banned keywords. This works after the fact. I would like their code to fail on compile so they don't turn in work.

My theory is that they have to make their main class extend from a "project" class that I provide. The project class blocks access to banned libraries - if possible.

Comment: Java 9 has a [module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). Possibly you can use that to unload the banned classes. Then you'd get a pretty severe run-time error if you try to use them. Of course, if any Java internals depend on them, then that would break too.

Comment: Why not provide your students with the project that they should then fork? Then it's as simple as looking at the diff between their Git branch and yours, to confirm that they haven't changed the build file.

Comment: What's the problem with "after the fact"? If you tell them what they shouldn't use and they still use it they'd get bad marks or you'd not accept the solution, would you? Wouldn't having the compiler disallow that just be to their advantage (enables easier trial and error)? Besides that, Eclipse (and other IDEs as well) supports to report errors on disallowed imports (like `com.sun....`). Alternatively using a build system would enable you to do the checks during build (e.g. by using checkstyle or something similar).

Comment: Would a solution that fails on execute rather than compile be of any use?  If so, you could use a custom class loader in the "project" class that they must extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has built in mechanisms for preventing classes from being loaded, namely the `SecurityManager`. It won't make the code fail to compile, but it would fail to run with an exception.

Create the `SecurityManager` for your needs and call to the students' projects. If they are using banned libraries, it will throw an exception.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

Comment: That is actually very easy. It didn't take any time to add a securityManager to a generic project class that checks to see if Swing.frame had a class constructor (which implies it was imported), and then fail miserably.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little hardcore for students, but you can easily solve the problem by using maven or gradle for compiling the project. Just add an ant-task or anything else to grep some text and fail the build.

But it force you to use maven or gradle to compile. And maybe you don't want that.